# want to pass values to parent component from child then wana get those value into another child component

Tags: reactjs

this is my parent component

```
class App extends Component {
constructor()
{
super();
this.state={counter:1,yourid:'',yourname:'',yourgender:''};
this.handleLogin=this.handleLogin.bind(this);
this.userview=this.userview.bind(this);
this.going=this.going.bind(this);


}
going(id,name,gender)
{
console.log("THIS IS DONE BY REACT GEEK:",id,name,gender);
this.setState({yourid:id,
  Yourname:name,
  Yourgender:gender});

}
```

this is my app.js render funtion

```
               <Login passingvalue={this.going} />
               <MessageView LoggedInUser={this.going} />
```

and here is my first child components from where i send values

```
export default class Login extends Component {
constructor(props)
{
super(props);
this.state={
    id:'',name:'',gender:''
}
this.show = this.show.bind(this);
this.sendingvalue=this.sendingvalue.bind(this)

}
sendingvalue()
{
this.props.passingvalue(this.state.id,this.state.name,this.state.gender);
// console.log('passing',Id);
console.log('hello this is going ',
this.state.id,
this.state.name,
this.state.gender)
}
```

and again here is my second child component where i want these values

```
export default class Messageonline extends Component {
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {Id:this.props.LoggedInUser.yourid,
            Name:this.props.LoggedInUser.yourname,
            Gender:this.props.LoggedInUser.yourgender};


}

    render() {
    return (
    <div className="messageshow">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="col-lg-10 "id="message_show">
    <h3>Inbox</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="col-lg-2" id="online_user" >
         <h3>online Users</h3>
         <span>{this.state.Id}</span>

         <br/>
         <span>{this.state.Name}</span>
         <br/>
         <span>{this.state.Gender}</span>
      </div>

      </div >
      </div>
```

there is any mistake thats why i cannot get those values in my second child..whats is that mistake i dont know ..tell me whats this mistake i want to fix that as soon as possible..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are passing the **going** method as the **LoggedInUser** prop to your **MessageView** component:

```
<MessageView LoggedInUser={this.going} />
```

You are probably looking to pass a user object instead.

Something like this:

```
<MessageView LoggedInUser={{
  yourid: this.state.yourid,
  yourname: this.state.yourname,
  yourgender: this.state.yourgender
}} />
```

Comment: i want to do this by passing method

Comment: The **going** method is updating the state of your parent component from your **Login** component and you want those values from the parent state to be passed to your **MessageView** component right? ...but you are passing the **going** method as the **LoggedInUser** prop so you won’t have access to **yourid**, **yourname** or **yourgender**, just the **going** method.

Comment: yup you are right.. but there is another way ??except passing state

Comment: You could look into using Redux if this sort of thing is common in your application.